# Need to infect a computer for testing - how do?

Tags: malware, virus

I'm trying to infect a laptop with malware for testing purposes and I just can't seem to do it. I've been searching for .exes that will just RUN and I can't find anything straight forward. Looking at this site all I can find are raw binaries but nothing really packaged and ready to go--unless I'm not looking in the right place.

It seems that a lot of malware research sites are geared towards software development and the actual investigation of the code itself but I just need an .exe that will work.

I never thought it would be this hard to deliberately infect a computer. Can someone please give me a link to a malware .exe or give me some tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, use the [Eicar](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) test file. Just copy it onto your machine, no need to install.

There are even variants, such as [zipped and double zipped](https://www.ikarussecurity.com/support/virus-info/test-viruses/) versions of that non-malicious test virus.

Comment: I've copied an EICAR test file to my machine and my AV does not pick it up. Nothing seems to happen. When I unzip the folder there's nothing in it.

Comment: @user1330287: because the Antivirus has already deleted it? Check the log and quarantine